# How to print nested linked list pretty

Tags: c, algorithm, printf

There is a structure like this:

```
struct a{
  char name[10];
  struct a* child;
  struct a* friend;
};
```

And there are many objects with this structure and they linked as children and friends

So I can access all of them if I know the first address

The first object’s is this:

```
struct a start;
```

And I'm gonna set all the values in those objects when right after they are generated

So if they don't have a child or a friend, their member variables of child and friend will be zero

And I wanna print all those objects like this:

```
a
└ aa
  └ aaa
  │  └ aaaa
  ab
  ac
  └ aca
    acb
    acc
```

I'm really sorry for this terrible drawing

So `a` is the name of `start` and `aa`
is a child's name of `start` and `ab`, `ac` are `aa`’s friends. Something like this.

I know how to print those special characters

The problem is that the objects are determined at run time

So I need an algorithm to print like that
Like this:

```
void print(struct a* b)
{
    if(b)
    {
        printf(”%s\n”, b->name);
        print(b->child);
        print(b->friend);
    }
}
```

But it's way far from that I want

I really don't know how to do that

Is it possible?
If not I wanna get some help on how to print such structure pretty

Comment: So... is there any difference in how you print children versus how you print friends?

Comment: @Mikhail children go to the right side right below their parents and friends goes to the same location with their friends after the friends printed all their children

Comment: This looks a bit like a homework dump and it is far to broad for this. You should ask your teacher for clarifications and advice.

Comment: Agree with @Broman. Also, you could have increased your chances of getting an answer, if you used more meaningful names than "a", "ab", etc.

Comment: You are going to need a recursive printing function which knows — or is told — how much to indent its own output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally, this type of tree printing is pretty straightforward: add a `depth` field and print blank spaces to indent children to match their nesting level.

Adding the `└` character is also doable with a boolean flag to tell a node whether it's a child or not, and if so, plop an angle character just before printing itself.

However, the addition of the child bar `|` throws a bit of a wrench in the works. Now, we need to keep state for every parent node to determine if it has children that haven't been printed yet. To do this, we can create an array of flags and tick them on or off according to the existence of children at a certain depth. It should be an expandable array since we can't be sure how deep the structure is.

Here's some example code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct node {
    char name[10];
    struct node* child;
    struct node* friend;
} node;

void print(node *root, int depth, bool *notch_locs, 
          size_t notch_locs_capacity, bool friend) {
    if (root) {
        for (int i = 0; i < depth * 2; i++) {
            if (friend && depth * 2 - 2 == i) {
                printf("└");
            }
            else if (i % 2 == 0 && notch_locs[i/2]) {
                printf("│");
            }
            else {
                printf(" ");
            }
        }

        if (depth >= notch_locs_capacity) {
            notch_locs_capacity *= 2;
            size_t size = sizeof(bool) * notch_locs_capacity;
            notch_locs = realloc(notch_locs, size);
        }

        notch_locs[depth] = root->child ? true : false;  
        printf("%s\n", root->name);
        print(root->friend, depth + 1, 
              notch_locs, notch_locs_capacity, true);
        print(root->child, depth, notch_locs, 
              notch_locs_capacity, false);
    }
}

void pprint(node *root) {
    bool *notch_locs = malloc(sizeof(bool));
    memset(notch_locs, false, sizeof(bool));
    print(root, 0, notch_locs, 1, false);
    free(notch_locs);
}

node *rand_chain() {
    int i = 0;
    node *root = malloc(sizeof(*root));
    memset(root, 0, sizeof(*root));
    sprintf(root->name, "%c", i + 97);
    i = (i + 1) % 25;

    while (rand() % 12) {
        node *curr = root;

        while (rand() % 5) {
            if (rand() % 2) {
                if (!curr->child) {
                    curr->child = malloc(sizeof(*curr));
                    memset(curr->child, 0, sizeof(*curr));   
                    sprintf(curr->child->name, "%c", i + 97);
                    i = (i + 1) % 25;
                }
                
                curr = curr->child;
            }
            else {
                if (!curr->friend) {
                    curr->friend = malloc(sizeof(*curr));
                    memset(curr->friend, 0, sizeof(*curr));
                    sprintf(curr->friend->name, "%c", i + 97);
                    i = (i + 1) % 25;
                }
                
                curr = curr->friend;
            }
        }
    }

    return root;
}

void free_chain(node *root) {
    if (root) {
        free_chain(root->child);
        free_chain(root->friend);
        free(root);
    }
}

int main(void) {
    /*
    a
    └ aa
      └ aaa
      │  └ aaaa
      ab
      ac
      └ aca
        acb
        acc
    */
    node acc = {"acc", NULL, NULL};
    node acb = {"acb", &acc, NULL};
    node aca = {"aca", &acb, NULL};
    node aaaa = {"aaaa", NULL, NULL};
    node aaa = {"aaa", NULL, &aaaa};
    node ac = {"ac", NULL, &aca};
    node ab = {"ab", &ac, NULL};
    node aa = {"aa", &ab, &aaa};
    node a = {"a", NULL, &aa};
    pprint(&a);

    node *root = rand_chain();
    pprint(root);
    free_chain(root);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
a
└ aa
  └ aaa
  │ └ aaaa
  ab
  ac
  └ aca
    acb
    acc
```

```
a
└ k
│ └ t
│ │ u
│ │ └ v
│ │   └ w
│ l
│ └ p
│ │ q
│ │ r
│ │ └ s
│ │   └ t
│ │     u
│ │     └ v
│ │       └ w
│ │         x
│ m
│ └ f
│ │ └ g
│ │   └ n
│ │     └ o
│ n
│ o
│ p
│ └ q
│   └ r
│     s
b
└ c
│ └ d
│ │ e
│ │ └ f
│ │ │ └ g
│ │ │   h
│ │ │   i
│ │ │   └ j
│ │ c
│ │ d
│ h
│ └ i
│   └ j
│     k
│     l
│     └ m
x
└ e
y
└ z
  b
```